# How do I use forEach to push into an array with React useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm trying to use the same code below in React. I've tried a couple ways but it doesn't work the same way.

working old code (not react code)

```js
const array = []
res = await getData()

res.data.forEach(item) => {
array.push({
   ...item, 
   isSelected: false, 
   id: getItemId(item.id) 
})
```

not working new code (React)

```js
const [array, setArray] = useState([])

const fetchItems = useCallback(async () => {
res = await getData()
const newData = res.data.forEach(item) => {
return [{...item, isSelected: false, id: getItemId(item.id) }]
})

setArray(newData)

}, [])

fetchItems()
console.log(array)
```

Is there a clean way to write this the same way it was done in the working code? Preferably without using `push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```js
const fetchItems = useCallback(async () => {
    res = await getData()
    const tempArr = res.data.map(item => ({...item, isSelected: false, id: 
    getItemId(item.id) }))
    setArray(tempArr)
}, [setArray, getData, getItemId])
```

but make sure your functions `getData`, `getItemId` wont change by wrapping them with `useCallback` as well or avoid using `useCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

In this change:

```
const newData = res.data.forEach(item) => {
```

What are you expecting [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to *return* and why?  Taking a step back... You already have working code, so just use your known working code.  Since the React component declares an `array` variable already, the only change you need to make is to rename your local variable:

```
const newArray = []
res = await getData()

res.data.forEach(item) => {
  newArray.push({
     ...item, 
     isSelected: false, 
     id: getItemId(item.id) 
  })
})
```

Then just update state to your new array:

```
setArray(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

```
const newData = res.data.map((item)=>{
  return {
    ...item,
    isSelected: false,
    id: getItemId(item.id)
  }
})

setArray(newData)
```

This will modify the value of the state .

Answer (score 0):

Replace your [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Because `Array.forEach` returns `undefined` but you expecting to have a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you should use `useEffect` rather than `useCallback` when fetching/editing data inside the component. In react you can write like this;

```js
  async function handleFetch() {
    const res = await getData();
    const newData = res.data.map((item) => {
      return [{ ...item, isSelected: false, id: item.id }];
    });
    setArray(newData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleFetch();
  }, []);
```

to mock data I wrote this ;

```js
function getData() {
  return { data: [{ isSelected: true, id: 1 }] };
}
```

And you can check out [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fhwkw6?file=src%2FApp.js)